# Bottom of the screen the menubar/toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-menu, android-tabs

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a LinearLayout with alignParentBottom="true"

Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/mainLyt"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<!-- Some layout things -->

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar">

<!-- some scrolling content -->
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<!-- Some Buttons -->
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I didn't try to compile, you might have to fix some typos but this is a basic idea with which you can achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the reply. what if i put a scrollview? the toolbar is not fix at the buttom.

Comment: It is fixed to the bottom because of the `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` parameter. I'll edit my example code to include a scrollview, one sec

Answer (score -2):

use the following lines after onCreat.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
```